# Invoke common method of different types (with generics?)

Tags: c#, generics

I have classes `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo` which separately implement a method with the same name: `Validate()`. I want to invoke the `Validate()` method on each of these classes from within my `Process<>()` method:

```
public void Process<T>(Map<T> map, T value)
{
    var validation = value.Validate();
    var result = map(value);
    SendEmail(result);
    SaveAsFile(value.ToString());
}
```

this method is intended to be used like this:

```
Process<ClassOne>(new ClassOneMap(), new ClassOne())
Process<ClassTwo>(new ClassTwoMap(), new ClassTwo())
```

But this is not working, because type `T` does not have a method `Validate()`.

What must I do to make `Process<T>()` work?

Comment: "Obviously this is not working for me." - why not? What happens? Some issues I can see right now is that there is a `new` missing before one of the ctor calls, and that sometimes, you write `Souce` instead of `Source`.

Comment: You have to create an interface with methods you'd like to use from within your method, make `SourceClassOne` and `SourceClassTwo` implement it, and add generic constraint to your method.

Comment: What is the return type of `map` supposed to be? Assuming it's `string` I think you want map to be of type `Func<T,string>` Or do you want the return to be generic as well? In that case `Process` needs to generic arguments `public void Process<TMapIn, TMapOut>(Func<TMapIn, TMapOut> map, TMapIn value)` If that's the case then SendEmail will also need to be generic.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - I can't even compile this. I get ''T' does not contain a definition for 'Validate' and no extension method 'Validate' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). Validate() is in fact, an extension method.

Comment: @MichaelWelch Map returns concrete type. Basically, what it is supposed to do is to map fields from T to that concrete type. It's just that how this mapping is done differs slightly when SourceClassOne vs SourceClassTwo are passed in. That's why specific maps are passed in.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - let me try this approach.

Comment: But what type does `map` return? If you want to invoke it as you do, it must be a `Func`. You can't just invoke any type as a function. Or is Map a delegate type of your own?

Comment: I fixed the question, so I am voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to introduce an abstract base class or, better yet, an interface called `Validatable` with a `Validate()` method, and you need to make each one of your types extend that abstract base class, or (better yet) implement that interface.

Then, your `Process()` method will look like this:

```
public void Process<T>(Map<T> map, T value) 
    where T: Validatable
{
}
```

Comment: This would work, along with what Marcin suggested. The problem is that I can not modify these classes, i.e. I can not make them implement Validatable or any other interface (I don't own the code). They do implement Validate() and ToString() as extension methods on their own, but not as part of an interface.

Comment: @user981375: Do you mean that there is a separate extension method `Validate()` for each type that you wish to pass to `T`?

Comment: In this case (facepalm, sob) you can wrap these objects in objects of yours which only expose `Validate` and `ToString()` and delegate to the contained objects whose code you don't own.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper All Ts implement Validate(), ToString(), RemoveEmpty() but implementations are not as part of an interface. These classes are closely related (almost identical schema) and implement above methods on their own. Validation of one type of T is internally different than other T, but they all return the same thing (list of errors in this case).

Comment: @MikeNakis I'll try this suggestion. Might not be pretty, but I'll try it. Thanks for your help!